# Scheduler in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office

Heya Is there any method or procedure to setup scheduling jobs in Sharepoint online. I would like to send notification every 15 days on list update.

Answer (score 3):

Use Azure WebJobs. It can be created using the following scripts:

.cmd, .bat, .exe (using windows cmd)
.ps1 (using powershell)
.sh (using bash)
.php (using php)
.py (using python)
.js (using node)

How it works:

1) Create a console application. Add the necessary SharePoint client dlls to it.

2) Write your business logic in the program

3) Zip the package and upload it or Publish it as Azure WebJob directly from Visual Studio.

4) You will get various configuration options related to scheduling.

5) Publish it and it will run as per your schedule.

Step by step guide - [Getting Started with azure WebJobs ("timer jobs") for your Office 365 Sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/getting-started-with-building-azure-webjobs-for-your-office365-sites)

Answer (score 0):

Consider also [Azure Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview):

> Azure Functions is a great solution for processing data, integrating
>   systems, working with the internet-of-things (IoT), and building
>   simple APIs and microservices. Consider Functions for tasks like image
>   or order processing, file maintenance, long-running tasks that you
>   want to run in a background thread, or for any tasks that you want to
>   run on a schedule.

The pricing model for Functions might be much cheaper for you, in comparison to azure jobs, which require Azure App Service.
Currently (as of January 2017) the [pricing model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) includes 400,000 GB-s for free. That mean, if you services are not heavy load (runs for many hours), you will get functions almost for free.

Here is an [example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-an-event-processing-function) creating scheduled function in C#.
MS also released recently template for VS 2015 to work with Azure Functions - [Visual Studio Tools for Azure Functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/), but it's rather new and may have bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for this requirement is to use Microsoft Flow at https://flow.microsoft.com/. In this you can create a **recurrence** step and use different steps for reading the list items and then for sending the notification.

Below is the screen shot on how you can do this. Refer the documentation at [How to learn flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/getting-started/) [image]